# How to deserialize object using bean.io?

Tags: java, json, serialization

I've got a class with bean.io annotations,

```
public class Entity {
    @Field(name = CustomFields.NAME, at = 1)
    private String field;

    @Field(name = CustomField.PHONE, at = 2)
    private String phone;
}
```

And I've got some JSON string, which I want to deserialize (with using field names from @Field annotations above)

How can I do this?